# Is there a keyboard shortcut for 3 fingers slide?

Tags: shortcut

I really like having applications in full screen mode and switch between them using the 3 finger swipe feature.

But can I have a shortcut for it? 
Maybe like command + -> , something like this?

Comment: is the Ctrl-Left or Right Arrow not working for you ?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

That would be the

> Ctrl-Left or Right Arrow

to slide between full screen applications.

Answer (score 29):

Yes.

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> do this by default.

Check under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control.

Comment: This answer was posted first, properly formatted and included information about where to go next, yet missed out on votes and accept :(

Comment: @grg Maybe the accept, but not the votes..

Comment: @grg I see now why I accepted Buscar, they commented first.. I am accepting that back.

Answer (score 18):

Also, you may want to try:

> CTRL + Up/Down Arrow

That's what you get for a 3 fingers slide.

Answer (score 2):

I just realised this. When working on multiple monitors, the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd> will work on the screen with the mouse pointer in it.

For example, if my mouse pointer is on the Mac screen, the shortcut will switch full screen apps opened on my Mac not on the externally connected monitor. This despite my keyboard cursor being present on the external monitor.

Comment: Yes this was included in OS X Mavericks I think, separating the desktops for each monitor.

Answer (score 2):

fn + Left = "fn" Mac Key + Right = 4 finger swipe left or right = Moves to other desktop. Apps that are in full screen will be put on other desktops.

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign applications to particular "desktops" or using desktop numbers.